# Google+ Api Latest Activities - returns result unordered?

Tags: api, google-plus

I refer to this documentation: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list

This is the URL where i load the data from:
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/116969347570193984320/activities/public?alt=json&maxResults=10&pageToken=1&key=[api_key]
(*replace [api_key] with your own api-key for testing or use the api-explorer on the page above*)

**For some reason, the api returns the results in some kind of random order!?**
If you compare the results with the actual G+ Page (https://plus.google.com/u/0/116969347570193984320/posts), you will see, that the returned results have these published-dates:

1. 2014-11-15 T15:11:21.929Z (should be 2.)
2. 2014-11-17 T07:58:11.342Z (should be 1.)
3. 2014-11-13 T15:11:12.151Z (should be 4.)
4. 2014-11-10 T15:11:39.184Z (should be 5.)
5. 2014-11-14 T15:11:13.404Z (should be 3.)
6. ...

I cannot add any url-parameter for ordering, according to the api-docs.
I also think this worked a long time, so what could be wrong here?

*ps: yes, i already did a google-search and also search on stackoverflow separatly.*

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, and yes it used to work correctly. Google is currently looking into it, so hopefully there's a fix soon.

For now you would have to order the result set yourself.

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1015